# How to access members for struct in struct - C

Tags: c

```
struct sniff_ip {
struct in_addr ip_src, ip_dst;
}

function{
const struct sniff_ip *ip;
ip = (struct sniff_ip*)(packet +SIZE_ETHERNET);

}
```

My goal here is to change the values of ip_src and ip_dst, but I can't figure out the correct syntax to modify src or dst when it is in a struct within a struct. I know to access a member within a struct is normally ip->member or (*ip).member , but this doesn't seem to be working for me here. What are the correct procedure(s) for accessing members in the event they are in a struct within a struct?

Edit: I want to change the ip addresses (values) for both src and dst. When using lines such as

"ip->ip_src="
or 
"ip->ip_src.s_addr=" , I get the error that
"assignment of read-only location '*ip'

Comment: You declared `const struct` so it's not allowing you to make assignments. If you want to assign to it don't declare your struct as`const` or do `struct sniff_ip * const ip`.

Comment: So I can change ip, but not the members inside ip?

Comment: I could go and try and write out an explanation, but it might be better to just look at this [article](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/cpp_mfc/general/article.php/c6967) instead.

Comment: Just a question but if you want to change the values for `ip_src` and `ip_dst` why declare `*ip` const at all?

Comment: This is an assignment and most of the code was prepared with some blank spots. I was told to do fill in the blanks while all the objects were already declared and initialized. I was not aware that the way certain structs were initialized may be wrong

Comment: It's not necessarily wrong. You can create a temporary sniff_ip struct and then assign its memory address to `*ip`. For example, `struct sniff_ip temp = {value1, value2}; ip = temp;` You won't be able to directly assign values to the members of `*ip` though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
struct in_addr other_addr;
ip->ip_src = other_addr;
```

Comment: I assumed you meant struct in_addr ip_src, ip_dst, other_addr;
This does not work as it says other_addr is undeclared.

Comment: @krikana No, I meant "if you have a `struct in_addr` named `other_addr`, and a `struct sniff_ip*` named `ip`, you may use `ip->ip_src = other_addr` to assign to the `ip_src` member of `ip`.

Comment: Okay. I tried your procedure, but I still get the error of assignment of read only location '*ip'

Comment: @krikara Have you marked something `const`? Is `ip` a `struct sniff_ip*` (note the very important star)?

Comment: All my code is shown in the main post. const struct sniff_ip *ip; 

As for initialized
ip = (struct sniff_ip*)(packet +SIZE_ETHERNET);

Comment: @krikara If you want to alter it, you don't want it to be `const`.

Answer (score 3):

You simply combine the operator in the correct places:

```
ip->ip_src.s_addr
```

Comment: In this situation, I was supposed to change the IP address for src and dst. However, once compiled, it says error: "assignment of read-only location '*ip' "

Is this a problem with the syntax?

Answer (score 0):

You problem is:

```
const struct sniff_ip *ip;
```

instead of:

```
struct sniff_ip const *ip = ...;
```

In your current declaration, you have `ip`, a pointer to a `const` data of type `struct sniff_ip`.